# Getting an Error when I make this gremlin query in IBM Graph service on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, graph-databases, gremlin, ibm-graph

When I issue this gremlin query using IBM Graph's gremlin endpoint I get an error

`curl  -u  username:password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"gremlin": "g = graph.traversal(); g.V(4144)"}' -X POST "http://../g/gremlin"`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IBM Graph, it's required that you explicitly declare all variables in a gremlin query before using them. So the above query should look something like that :

curl  -u  username:password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"gremlin": "**def** g = graph.traversal(); g.V(4144)"}' -X POST "http://../g/gremlin"